# Tidy type casting of tibble columns based on target type specification

Tags: r, casting, type-conversion, coercion, vctrs

Is there a recommended way of "tidy type casting", i.e. of coercing the columns of a `tibble` to desired types/classes based on a target specification?

Since [`vctrs`](https://vctrs.r-lib.org/) seems to come up with new tidy "nuts and bolds" for vectors, I'd probably prefer a solution that's based on `vctrs`. While I have something that works, I was wondering if there are even better ways of "tidy type casting" (if that's the correct conceptual term for that) than using a mix of:

1. base R things like `factor()` and `numeric()`
2. methods of `vctrs::vec_cast()`
3. and handling the map part via `purrr::map2_df()`

This is what I could come up with so far:

```
library(magrittr)
#> Warning: package 'magrittr' was built under R version 3.5.2

# Data ----
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col_a, ~col_b,
  "a",   "1",
  "b",   "2",
  "c",   "3"
)

# Approach via readr::cols and readr::type_convert -----
col_types <- readr::cols(
  readr::col_factor(),
  readr::col_double()
)

df %>% 
  readr::type_convert(col_types = col_types)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   col_a col_b
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 b         2
#> 3 c         3

# Approach via vctrs::vec_cast -----
col_types <- list(
  factor(),
  numeric()
)

df %>%
  purrr::map2_df(col_types, function(.x, to) {
    vctrs::vec_cast(.x, to)
  }) 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   col_a col_b
#>   <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 b         2
#> 3 c         3
```

Created on 2019-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.2.1)

What surprised me is that the approach via `readr::type_convert()` seems to ignore the fact that `col_a` should become a `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

The `cols()` function expects named parameters. So

```
col_types <- readr::cols(
  col_a = readr::col_factor(),
  col_b = readr::col_double()
)
```

would work with

```
df %>% 
  readr::type_convert(col_types = col_types)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. A bit strange though that it works for the double, but not for the factor, isn't it?

Comment: Well, if you don't pass any parameters, it will convert it to double anyway (see `df %>% readr::type_convert()`) so it's basically just ignoring what you pass in. The default is `col_guess()` so it's guessing that since all your character values are numbers, that you wanted a numeric column.